# No module named Tkinter error

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been using *http://python.codnex.net/index.php*. I have tried to use Tkinter but it shows `ImportError: No module named Tkinter on line 1`

I have tried many things including:

- `import Tkinter`
- `import tkinter`
- `from tkinter import *`

If you find something please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question & answer](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-run-my-Tkinter-code-online) in Quora you **can't use tkinter with online interpreters**. Though apparently you can run linux along chromeOS if you have non-school version.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but I believe it's because tkinter is a GUI module, which can't be ran from a webbrowser.
Have you tried importing it in a local python instance?

Answer (score 0):

it wont work on web browser ,Run a local python instance and import tkinter after installing tkinter by using command prompt using the command pip install python-tk